# How to use findViewById in a function inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wanna find some layouts in a function written in a fragment but I always get a `NullPointerException` here is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,null);

        return v;
    }

public void myfunction(String etat) {

        LinearLayout myLayout3 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(
                    R.id.f_2);
```

Comment: Create your `LinearLayout` as public variable for your `Fragment` and initialise it in `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()`.

Comment: where is your variable v declared? if it's not an instance variable you can't access that way.

Answer (score 1):

In a fragment you can retrieve views with `getView().findViewById(int viewId)`

Answer (score 0):

If `v` is a member of your fragment, then you must be calling `myfunction` before it is initialised in onCreateView.

You can use `getView()` instead, but you can't use it in a method that is being called from `onCreateView` (since `getView` will still return null until `onCreateView` returns).

If you want the method to be called during `onCreateView`, pass `v` into it as an argument.

Comment: I tried getView() and it doesn't work, i found the one i'm using now in this link http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-passing-data-between-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

I find it's best to inflate your layout in onCreateView but then retrieve views in onActivityCreated. The view can take some time to inflate so trying to call findViewById might not work (or return null) as the the view hierarchy might not be instantiated and the view may not have been rendered.

From Docs:

> onActivityCreated: Called when the fragment's activity has been
>   created and this fragment's view hierarchy instantiated. It can be
>   used to do final initialisation once these pieces are in place, such
>   as **retrieving views** or restoring state. This is called after
>   onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) and before
>   onViewStateRestored(Bundle).

Also bear in mind, in your example code, the view you are trying to retrieve (R.id.f_2) has to exists in the the layout inflated in v (R.layout.main)?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i tried onviewcreated which do the same but it doesn't work when i apply smth else on the layout in my function

Comment: Put the code for your entire class in a pastebin, provide comments where you are having issues and paste a link here. Seeing the whole class will make it easier to help. :-) http://pastebin.com/